# AWS Aurora mysql database is very slow then AWS RDS Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have existing data in on-premise mysql version 5.7 and planning to move application and database on AWS. we provisioned one RDS Mysql database and one Aurora Mysql db and connect application to both server. we saved execution timing in database so we found that **RDS MySql is running 2times fast rather then Aurora database**.
AWS claim that performance of Aurora database is 5 times faster then RDS Mysql, but it seems this is not correct.
Please suggest is there any tuning required with Aurora db.

System configuration for both DB: **db.r6g.large (2CPU and 16 GB RAM)**

Note : refer db column prodQueryTime as 'Mysql performance time' and experimentQueryTime as 'Aurora DB performance time'
[image: Query stats]

Comment: The only useful benchmark is _your_ application.  And it may be 2x or 5x or some other multiple or fraction.

Comment: Additional information request, from your RDS and Aurora instance, please. 
any SSD or NVME devices on each MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you could post data requested, it is likely our suggestions would improve your performance for answering queries.

Comment: @kartavya soni our server workload tuning analysis will provide suggestions to save time and money.

Answer (score 2):

There are many similar reports like yours, e.g. [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=213445). And the answer is that it depends what you do. AWS rep writes:

> The most important aspect to keep in mind is that Aurora is optimized for concurrent workloads and its benefits are best **evaluated by running parallel benchmarks**.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree.

Aurora MYSQL performance is hugely worse than common MYSQL for our Task (iOS & Android App, accesded by 500K users)

We migrated from RDS MYSQL (t3.medium) to Aurora MYSQL.
We tried Aurora MYSQL and Aurora MYSQL Severless V2.

Originally, our MYSQL t3.medium was just running fine, CPU (20-50%) all time.
The same size of Aurora could not handle the load. We had to duplicate the instance size and keep having issues during peak times.

Also, testing Aurora Serverless v2, we had to scale to 8ACU (16GB) to be able to handle the load.

As I said before, with MYSQL (No aurora), we could handle the load just fine with t3.medium (2CPU, 4GB).

With Aurora we had to duplicate (or more) the instance size, so the cost doubled (or more).

Going back to normal RDS MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

tried to just count 4 tables...

count(id) from tbl_a (size 180GB - 358,598,168 records)

count(id) from tbl_b (size 75GB - 41,942,923 records)

count(id) from tbl_c (size 109GB - 41,942,398 records)

count(id) from tbl_d (size 22GB - 41,946,822 records)

- MariaDB 10.3.36 on db.t3.small (<10% CPU all the time)

tbl_a -> 123.787s

tbl_b -> 38.767s

tbl_c -> 37.544s

tbl_d -> 15.326s

- Aurora MySQL 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2 on Serverless v2, 32 ACUs (~65% CPU all the time)

tbl_a -> 463.085s

tbl_b -> 1055.491s

tbl_c -> 1360.827s

tbl_d -> 85.151s

It's nightmare!!!. something terrible wrong with Aurora MySQL or Serverless v2.
going back to MariaDB.

Note:

db.t3.small -> 2vCPU, 2GiB RAM

Serverless v2, 32 ACUs -> 64GiB RAM

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Serverless is that it scales based on CPU usage hence when you need more memory such as for count queries, it would take forever as evident from @apiwat answer above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).